# Instance Message Error in Objective-C, What does this mean? And why is it happening?

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, aes, nsdata

I get the below error hor no apparent reason, I would try to fix it myself but I can't understand what it means. Does anyone else understand it? Here is the error and below it is the code.

Error: **Receiver Type 'NSdata' for instance message does not declare a method with selector type 'EncryptAES:'**

I have added a comment to the line with the error on it:

```
//Change the Input String to Data
NSData *objNSData = [NSData dataWithData:[Input dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//Encrypt the Data
[objNSData EncryptAES:Keyword.text]; //Error appears here
NSString *InputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:objNSData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

What does this mean, why is it happening and what can I do to fix it?

And, what *is* an instance message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `NSData` does not respond to the `EncryptAES:` selector. You can only invoke selectors that exist on the class. With the Objective-C runtime's loose typing, you can also invoke a selector on a class that does not respond to said selector, as long as the selector appears in the implementation of at least one other class that the compiler is working with.

All standard `NSData` methods can be found on the [NSData Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Apple has sample code for encryption, but it is not built-in to `NSData`.

Comment: So would I have to rewrite this code? Or is there a way in CommonCrypto to accomplish this task?

Comment: You can use CommonCrypto to do this.

Comment: Honestly, the files Apple has on CommonCrypto confuse me I am just a beginner so this is rocky water. BUT I am already using CommonCrypto. If I have imported it in the top of the file, does that mean I am using it? I have asked questions, but answers aren't clear. It seems like this code should make sense but I guess it doesn't with Xcode

Comment: CommonCrypto does not add `NSData` encryption methods. You will need to copy some sample code online, or ask another question on stackoverflow. This question is not targeted towards encryption, but instead the Objective-C runtime.

Comment: Then what does it encrypt? NSString? hmmmm

Comment: CommonCrypto can encrypt data, but it is not as simple as calling a method on `NSData`. You have to use, well, CommonCrypto methods. I suggest that you mark my answer correct, as I did answer your question. Then, ask a new question pertaining to the new topic of encryption.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4282/discussion-between-alex-nichol-and-razorsharp)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're trying to use the AESEncrypt "category" for NSData, but you don't actually have the category installed in your project.

Comment: Where did you get the .h file for AESEncrypt?  Get the .m file from the same source.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, there was no AESEncrypt File and the error was supposed to say EncryptAES: not AESEncrypt: